# Regex in PySpark removing a row with a specific work anywhere in the string

Tags: regex, pyspark

I'm trying to filter out rows with a specific word anywhere in the string of a column row. Specifically, I want to remove all rows with the word `final` in the string.

I have the following so far:

```
df.filter(col("COLUMN").rlike("(?i)^*final$"))
```

But it's only removing rwos when the word final is in the beginning of the string. How would you put together a pyspark compatible regex to find a word anywhere in the string. Beginning, middle or end.

Comment: Maybe `.rlike("(?i)\\bfinal\\b"))`?

Comment: can you not just use `df.filter(func.col('column').like('%final%') == False)`?

Comment: `df.filter(~F.col("COLUMN").rlike(r"(?i)\bfinal\b"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex solution then the below should work

```
df.filter(F.col("COLUMN").rlike("^((?!final).)*$")).show()
```